# Will a pointer p1 be accessible after freeing another pointer p2 containing the same address as p1?

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

Is there some sort of risk that the program might go to segmentation fault if you assign a pointer the same address to another pointer with another type definition of the same struct, then you free the previous one and just use the last assigned with the same address?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Class{
 int data;
 struct Class *next;
}key;

int main(){
 key *newclass = malloc(sizeof(*newclass));
 newclass->data = 5;
 newclass->next = NULL;
 
 key *newclass2;
 newclass2 = newclass;
 
 newclass = NULL;
 free(newclass);

 printf("%d", newclass2->data);
 
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is illegal. Both pointers point to the same memory, which is `free`d. After that both pointers point to an invalid location.

Comment: Actually, the `free(newclass);` call will do nothing ... because of the preceding `newclass = NULL;` line. And `newclass2` will still point to the *original* allocated memory.

Comment: `free()` releases the memory, if any, to which its argument points.  This makes *all* pointers (in)to the freed region invalid.  It has little to do with the variable, if any, from which `free()`'s argument was taken.  Certainly `free()` itself has no visibility into that.

Comment: You don't `free` *pointers*, you `free` *memory*. Pointer is just something that is telling which memory to `free`.

Comment: It may be worth looking into the C notions of "object" (unrelated to OOP objects) and "storage duration" (automatic, static, thread, dynamic).

Comment: `key *newclass = malloc(sizeof(*newclass));` <<-- `key` is not a typedef name, but a (global) variable.

Comment: @wildplasser Excuse me, but what do you mean?

Comment: You omitted the (intended) `typedef` keyword. So your source code was invalid syntax.

Comment: @wildplasser Ok, so I had to define it inside a function like main, in order to get the non-ommitted ``typedef``   definition?

Comment: No, your `struct Class{
 int data;
 struct Class *next;
}key;` defines a global struct Class instance, named `key`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it seems there are typos in the structure definition. I think you mean

```
typedef struct Class{
 int data;
 struct Class *next;
}key;
```

After this assignment

```
 newclass2 = newclass;
```

the both pointers point to the same dynamically allocated memory.

Then the pointer `newclass` was reassigned with NULL

```
 newclass = NULL;
```

So calling the function free for a null pointer

```
 free(newclass);
```

has no effect.

The pointer `newclass2` still points to the dynamically allocated memory that you should free then it is not required anymore.

```
 free(newclass2);
```

If you will remove this assignment

```
 newclass = NULL;
```

then after calling free with this pointer

```
 free(newclass);
```

the value stored in the pointer `newclass2` will be invalid and you may not use it to access the already freed memory.

But the both pointers as local variables are still alive and you may assign to them new values.

Comment: For starters, you *did* read the original code after all ...

Comment: @wildplasser And what is wrong?

Comment: Thanks Vlad for the explanation, I don't know why I did assign to NULL this pointer, but after deallocating the pointer newclass, by calling in the right way free, so the memory heap is not available anymore, but the pointers can still point to somewhere else accessible?

Comment: @Hynem If you will reassign them with addresses of something accessible then they will have valid values. Otherwise after freeing the allocated memory the pointers have invalid values (I assume that you did not set pointers to NULL before freeing the memory)

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is simply an index into a memory. It's not the 'data' itself that it's pointing at. It's the index of the memory it's pointing at.

I'm going to make an assumption here and say that

```
newclass = NULL;
```

is done by mistake because if not you now have a memory leak.

There is nothing wrong with having multiple pointers pointing into the same memory if you manage all those pointers properly (talking purely about technicality and not making any statements regarding on whether this is a bad practice or not.).
Problem is that, if you deallocate that memory and forget to manage even a single one of those pointers and try to do an operation on that deallocated memory block via that pointer, than that's definitely a problem.

The fact that the memory block a pointer is pointing to gets deallocated doesn't deallocate the 'pointer' itself. You can still use your pointers for various stuff; from pointer arithmetic to making them point to a different block of memory. Golden rule is not doing any memory operations on the memory address your pointer was previously indexing.

Comment: The `newclass = NULL:` assignment is odd, but is neither a bug nor a memory leak.  There's another pointer, `newclass2`, that points to the address, and the memory can be freed by using `free(newclass2)`.  The assignment also means that the `free(newclass);` call does nothing useful.

Comment: Of course we can still free the memory via the other pointer but as the OP didn't freed it later, that was my reason for saying it was a memory leak. I said it's a memory leak based on the code OP posted.

Also yes, free(NULL) does nothing as you've stated. reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free